# Jetpack compose navigation with hiltViewModel cannot find constructor

Tags: navigation, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt, jetpack-compose-navigation

I have a NavHost in my app defined as follow:

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    Scaffold(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        bottomBar = {
            BottomBar(navController = navController)
        }
    ) {
        NavHost(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(it),
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = "main",
        ) {
            navigation("B", route = "main") {
                composable("A") {
                    ScreenA(navigate = { navController.navigate(route = "new") })
                }
                composable("B") { ScreenB() }
            }
            navigation("C", route = "new") {
                composable("C") {
                    ScreenC(onBack = {
                        navController.popBackStack()
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Inside ScreenC I have a `val viewModel = hiltViewModel<ScreenCViewModel>()` (as in ScreenA and ScreenB).
The init of `ScreenCViewModel` causes an exception as it says there is no constructor found for that viewModel.
All viewModels are marked with the `@HiltViewModel` annotation, all dependencies are sorted with `@Provides` or `@Binds`.
I'm sure I'm missing a tiny bit of configuration for the graph. Any idea?

Comment: Does your view model have a constructor annotated with `@Inject`?

Comment: Share your viewmodel code as well. so that it can be traced

Comment: @Leviathan yes, '@Inject constructor(dep1: Dep1)'

Comment: @ChiragThummar the VM is basically empty, it has a constructor annotated with '@Inject' and 1 dependency. Removing that dependecy solve the problem, but having that dependecy in other VMs doesn't make them crash, so it's not related to the dependency in question only

Comment: Well, without giving us the full picture we can only guess. For further analysis we would need a working example that reproduces the error.

Comment: Also check if you have applied Hilt compiler to the module containing the view model.

Comment: Hilt compiler is applied to the module containing the viewModel. I guess otherwise the other viewModels would have problems as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was totally un-related to navigation, annotations, dependencies or anything you **might** think about.

The problematic `ViewModel` and related Screen (Composable function) were placed in a package named `new`, in something like this: `com.lucanicoletti.app.screens.reminders.new`.

`new` is a reserved keyword which you can't use in package names, if you try to do so, you'll get a warning
[image: warning]

But that's all you'll get. You won't be stopped nor shown any prompt to warn you once more. You're free to hit enter and create that package with that name.
Once you do so, you can notice that there is a difference between a valid package name and a non-valid one in the `Project Structure` of `Android Studio`:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Without the full picture it's hard to guess as @Leviathan said. Anyway, the only two think I can think of are

1. You forgot a dependency inside your module
2. You forgot to add `@AndroidEntryPoint` and/or the delegate  by viewModels()` when declaring the viewmodel inside the App /Fragment/Screen...

Nothing else comes up in my mind, sorry.

Comment: The dependency that the ViewModel has causes no problem if used inside the two other ViewModels (used in the first two screens).
The only activity that I have has the annotation.